# iOS asihttp nslog request

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, nslog

I need to log the request used in ASIHTTP

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:// tor.or rd.net.au/OnlineService.svc/JSON/G "];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request setPostValue:@"b07db55065b922fdae9" forKey:@"token"];
    [request setPostValue:@"2312" forKey:@"points"];

    [request startSynchronous];
    //hasta aqui!
    NSString *response = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"the request ::%@", request );

    NSLog(@"respond ::%@", response);
```

but I get this in my nslog

```
     the request ::<ASIFormDataRequest: 0x7b62a00>
```

I would like to see the URL and the body (dictionary)

so how can i format the response to be logged,
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question a few days ago. Figured it out, here's the solution:

Go to ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h file and look for line 20. It will be

```
 // When set to 1, ASIFormDataRequests will print information about the request body to the console 
#ifndef DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST
#define DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST 0
#endif
```

So to log the request body simply change 0 to 1. So it will be like that:

```
 // When set to 1, ASIFormDataRequests will print information about the request body to the console 
#ifndef DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST
#define DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST 1
#endif
```

Enjoy. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

`ASIFormDataRequest` is a subclass of `ASIHTTPRequest`,

to see URL, use `NSLog(@"the request ::%@", [request originalURL]);`

Answer (score 1):

That is the request. It is a log of the pointer to the request object. What else are you looking for?

Comment: hi, thanks, I would like to see the pointer content?, URL and body with dictionary?, cheers

Comment: Check further down, the other answers should be accurate.